# Initializing and displaying grid - python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, grid

I'm attempting to create a game similar to battleship, and I'm having trouble figuring out how I would initialize the board by having each cell begin with an 'O' and displaying it to the user. A requirement for the function player_board() is that it's supposed to take in a grid representing the player's game board as an argument and output it to the user's screen. This is a portion of my code that I'm struggling with. I'm also not sure why it keeps printing out an extra 'O' at the end. Any help or feedback would be appreciated!

```
import random
sizeof_grid = 9
chance = 10
def mines():
    grid = [{("M" if random.randint(0, chance) == 0 else " ") for i in 
range(sizeof_grid)} for i in range(sizeof_grid)]
    return grid

def initialize_board():
    start_board=[["O" for i in range(sizeof_grid)] for i in range(sizeof_grid)]
    return start_board

def players_board(): 
    for r in initialize_board(): 
        for c in r:
            print (c, end="") 
        print()
    return c
print(players_board())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the extra "O: because of the last line of code. You call the function with print(players_board) and in the function itself you return c (which has the value of one "O"). This means you print out the return value of the function which is "O".

You can execute the function with players_board() and remove the print().

Also you can remove the return c at the bottom of the function.